# Which of the following functions lie in the span of the vector-valued functions

Tags: linear-algebra

Here are the following functions:

$f_1(x) = \begin{pmatrix}
1\\x
\end{pmatrix}$, $f_2(x) = \begin{pmatrix}
x\\1
\end{pmatrix}$, $f_3(x) = \begin{pmatrix}
x\\2x
\end{pmatrix}$

Do these functions span this vector?

$\begin{pmatrix}
2\\1
\end{pmatrix}$

Here's what I tried...

Assume the following

$\begin{pmatrix}
2\\1
\end{pmatrix} = c_1\begin{pmatrix}
1\\x
\end{pmatrix} + c_2\begin{pmatrix}
x\\1
\end{pmatrix} + c_3\begin{pmatrix}
x\\2x
\end{pmatrix}$

Then as a system of equations we have:

(1)  $2 = c_1 + c_2x + c_3x$

(2)  $1 = c_1x + c_2 + 2c_3x$

Converting into augmented matrix and performing back substitution:

$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
 1 &  x &  x & 2 \\
x & 1 & 2x & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right)
$

I'm confused on what I should do next. Was it correct, to add the x's to the augmented matrix?

I know that you're supposed to solve for the $c_i$'s. I also know that the solution is supposed to be $c_1 = 2$, $c_2 = 1$, $c_3 = -1$ but I have to show how I got that answer.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What "following functions" and what "span" are you referring to?

Comment: Solve for $c_i$'s